# Embedding Post Editor Into External Site

Tags: posts, block-editor, editor, embed

I want users of my spring boot site to be able to write/edit posts from the spring site itself using the Wordpress editor. I have found that there are ways to use the Wordpress API to post the content via that. Is there a way to embed the wordpress editor istelf into my site as that would make development a lot easier? I primarily want to use wordpress for showing the posts but handle the writing and editing myself, I understand that might not be the Wordpress way of doing things.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to display the posts with WordPress, and you want to edit the posts with the WordPress editor...? It really sounds like you should just use WordPress!

Comment: I want to be able to show some of the posts on our site but I also want people to write them in our admin dashboard. I only really want wordpress as a CMS. Its fine is its not possible.